# Can't select secondary attribute size until primary attribute color is selected

Tags: product, product-attribute

I can't select secondary attribute  "size" until primary attribute "color" is selected. Is there a way to allow the customer to select either size or color first? I.e., I want the customer to be able to select blue and see all the available sizes or select a size and see the available colors.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend you [this free extension](https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher).
it doesn't do exactly what you need because of the way the configurable products are build in Magento, but it kind of simulates what you need.
You can define a "pre-selected" combination of color and size and the user will not be required to select size first. He can choose any of the configurable attributes in any order.
The downside is that if you select a color first and then change the size and the selected size does not allow the selected color the color will be reset. If the selected color is available in the selected size it will remain selected so the customer is not required to select again.
Full description of what the extension does can be [found here](https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher/wiki)

Answer (score 0):

Not possible by core. Only by extension.
Search for "magento color swatches extension" there are some like
http://amasty.com/color-swatches-pro.html - but it is a paid extension.

Answer (score 0):

If magento feature you need to customization of this.

If want to chane sort order size and color on product the go to class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable and change on function getJsonConfig or
m
most suitable

goto admin>Mange Attribute set and change the size and color attribute position on attribute set

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in Magento 1.9.1 with swatches, than you can start anywhere.